# How to keep a website loaded in a Service?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to Android Development. I'm trying to load a website in the background thread precisely in a service. I'm aware of the fact that Webview can't be used inside of a background thread so any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal service class. since services run on the same UIThread, you can easily use the WebView in there.

simply extend from Service and create a Webview in there and start using your service by binding to it or any other way.

just remember to start a foreground service, not a regular one. otherwise, OS will crash your app on API level above 26.

happy coding

Comment: Can i use broadcast reciever to start service on Startup?

Comment: you can use STICKY flag in your service. to keep it running as long as you want. (even on OS restart android will run your service again automatically). just remember the foreground service and notification.

Comment: So when i return the on Start as 'Start_Sticky' and start the service, the next time i bootup the service starts automatically?